# Fixed JavaScript Warning - Pin to Top of Page Using CSS Position

Tags: css, javascript, noscript

I am working on a `noscript` chunk of code whereby I do some stuff that includes a `<p>` at the top of the page that alerts the users that he/she has JavaScript disabled.

The end result should look like the Stack Exchange sites when JavaScript is disabled (here is a screenshot of mine - SE looks similar except it is at the very top of the page):

[image]

I have it working OK, but I would love it if the red bar stayed fixed along the top, upon scrolling.

I tried using the `position: fixed;` method, but it ends up moving the `p` element and I can't get it to look exactly the same as it does without the `position: fixed;` modification.  I tried fiddling with CSS `top` and `left` and other positioning but it doesn't ever look like I want it to.

Here is a CSS snippett:

```
<noscript>

<style type="text/css">

p.noscript_warning {
    position: fixed;
}

</style>

</noscript>
```

Comment: You might want to close the style tag. Better still, put a noscript tag in the head and link to an external CSS file (it's only small, I know, but it's best practice to do so). I am not 100% sure if noscript tags are valid, however.

Comment: Also try setting the `top`, `left`, and `right` properties to 0 and also the `height`. That should achieve the effect you're looking for in everything except IE 6. It may also be worth fixing the position and dimensions for the main content container in the noscript stylesheet so that it doesn't go behind the fixed paragraph.

Comment: Sorry, I actually just copied it in chunks and forgot the ending style tag.  It's there in my code ;--)  Thanks for the top, left, right properties.  I played with these a bit, and didn't get my desired result, but maybe I wasn't doing it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not have a space after the `.`.

```
p.noscript_warning {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* For Browser Compatibility */
}
```

Check out the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twM7F/) here... :)

Comment: Good fiddle.  Mine is working better now.  The only piece left is padding the body and I'm doing that now.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey, quick follow up...  I'm trying to keep it on top of everything else and z-index doesn't seem to do it (maybe because all elements aren't set with the right position properties).  Is there an alternate way to stack this ribbon on top of everything else?  Thanks again!

Comment: Give the `z-index` to the maximum possible. If it doesn't work, for IE 6 / 7, you need to give `position: relative` to `body`.

Comment: Thank you - I ended up finding the `div` that was causing the problem, and gave it a `z-index` of `0` and then changed the `z-index` of the `noscript_warning` to `10`.  This seemed to do the trick ;--)  Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, that is what you should do with IE. Forgot to tell you that! :)

Comment: Note that there is an issue in IE6 with selects - if you have a language dropdown at the top right, for example, and it appears 'under' the banner, you will need to shunt it down or hide it as selects appear over everything else in IE 6. The only work around is to hide them if you have an overlay, for example. Its not a bug, its a feature!

Comment: Why not hide the whole page with an overlay?  Even Facebook requires javascript to be turned on.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes all you need to do is change the document header when using position fixed. For some reason windows is picky about that. If your doctype is strict you need to change it to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p. noscript_warning {
  position: fixed;
  margin:0;
  top:0; /* Not necessarily */
}
```